# Font Awesome 4.0 new syntax

Tags: css, fonts, sass, font-awesome

I started using Font Awesome this week, and now there is an update to 4.0. My questions are:

1. I have been using the mixin in older versions and just updated the name. Is this okay and legal, etc., since I see a lot of name changes?

   ```
   @mixin fa-FontAwesome() {
     font-family: FontAwesome;
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
     text-decoration: inherit;
     -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
     *margin-right: .3em; // fixes ie7 issues
   }
   ```
2. Can anyone explain the syntax now used? I appreciate any information as I am new and learning SCSS and Font Awesome.

   For example: `.#{$fa-css-prefix}` uses a number sign and curly brackets in a class name. I would like to understand the logic behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your mixin is just fine.
2. That syntax uses string interpolation to set the prefix for the Font Awesome base class, which is `fa`, via a variable.

For example:

```
$fa-css-prefix: fa;
.#{$fa-css-prefix} { ... }
```

Will compile to this css:

```
.fa { ... }
```

Which is used this way:

```
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>
.fa {
  &.fa-camera-retro {
  }
}
```

In theory, using variables, you can set your own prefix. It doesn't have to be `fa`.

Comment: Is the update backwards compatible (can I use my old icon class names)?

Comment: No, it's not backward compatible.

Answer (score 0):

FontAwesome's updated site explains this really well, [just read through the examples page](http://fontawesome.io/examples/).